# Unreachable statement in fragemnt

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, findviewbyid, unreachable-statement

I am not getting the problem that why it is showing in the fragment:
this is the code. The problem is occurring due to return statement we are using in inflator.

```
public class Information extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView deleteNoticeRecyler;
    private ArrayList<AlertData> list;
    private AlertsAdapter adapter;
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public Information() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static Information newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Information fragment = new Information();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_information, container, false);

        deleteNoticeRecyler = getView().findViewById(R.id.deleteNoticeRecycler);

        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notice");

        deleteNoticeRecyler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        deleteNoticeRecyler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        getAlerts();

    return null;
    }
    private void getAlerts(){
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot  : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    AlertData data = snapshot.getValue(AlertData.class);
                    list.add(data);
                }
                adapter = new AlertsAdapter(getContext(),list);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                deleteNoticeRecyler.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),databaseError.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

picture of my issue

[image: Problem picture]

Because of this same problem my other my other problems related to findViewbyid is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your return statement at the end of the onCreateView() method, the return keyword marks the execution endpoint hence its unreachable.